# Why span tag goes down to a subline

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/p3qwz4xu/

How can i solve it. I want the entire phone number on the same line.

Output

```
Call 1234 456
789
```

Desired Output

```
Call 1234 456 789
```

HTML will not change.

```css
.call {
  margin-left: 3%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.phone {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="test">
      <span class="call">Call</span>
      <span class="phone">1234 456 789</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you're using bootstrap and as you haven't set a width for test (eg col-12 or other such class) it is not 100% width - https://jsfiddle.net/p3qwz4xu/9/

Comment: Your `.test` div width is causing this.  Probably something to do with being a child `div` of a `.row`.  If you set a css `min-width` for `.test` you should be good.

Comment: @Sirko solved my problem thank you. I searched , but I couldn't find it.

Comment: If you still are interested in the cause of this behavior, it was percentage margin of `.call`. The percentage margins in the containers that have content-based width (`.test`, which is a flex item) work so that browsers first calculates the width of content assuming them as 0, then calculates the percentage of that width, reducing the available width inside the container.

Comment: I object closing this as a duplicate. Linked answers say only _how_ to work around this issue, but the OP also asks _why_ does it behave this way, which is left unanswered. Probably https://stackoverflow.com/q/24112923/2533215 would be more relevant!